# What are the pros and cons of initializing a static variable in a static block as opposed to say, inline?

Tags: java, static, initialization

For e.g. is there any advantage to doing this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private static final SimpleDateFormat yyyyMMddFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
}
```

as opposed to doing this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private static final SimpleDateFormat yyyyMMddFormat;
    static {
        yyyyMMddFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I find the first one much more aesthetically pleasing, but as far as I know there is not a difference between them. I'm curious if perhaps someone else knows more though.

Answer (score 1):

In the block, you can also do some processing if your initialization wasn't so straightforward.  LIke if you were initializing a collection.

```
static{
    for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++){
        // new stuff
    }
}
```

where as you cannot do this from inline.

As far as the inline way, if you don't need the extra processing, its much cleaner looking.